# Google map not displaying

Tags: android

Google Map is not displayed , do not know why ?? 
Application runs but shows no Map only the other xml stuff is shown which I added in xml file.
I added the google play services_lib and android.support.v4.jar . Also I got the key with right method . 
kindly cooperate i am stuck in here !

Manifest file ,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.map"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

  <permission
    android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<!--
     The following two permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.

-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

     <service android:name=".TransitionsIntentService" />


        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBeJoGKnhxYps-youI1xfMZn6S2G05l0PM" />
       <meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

       </application>    
   </manifest>
```

Java file,

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

protected GoogleMap gMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (gMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps not available",           
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
       }
```

XML file,

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
      <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true" />
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: r u running on emulator?

Comment: do you have any errors on the logcat?

Comment: Is your API key is must be sure generated right? Also Have you running the app in Emulator?

Comment: @Sobat didn't tell you. Its tell to me.. Don't worry

Comment: Logcat errors,  The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
Authorization failure.  Please  see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set  up the map.
    E/Google Maps Android API(5184): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
 I/Google Maps Android API(5184): Failed to contact Google servers.  Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.

Answer (score 3):

Please get map key with your keystore.

1. Create your own keystore.
2. Register app with new SHA1 over cloud console.
3. replace the map key in manifest.
4. sign app with your newly created keystore and get apk.
5. install apk and run app

Comment: I have apk installed at my device

Comment: sorry not getting your point here. please uninstall previous apk file sign with your own keystore and install again

Comment: logcat errors,   The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.Authorization failure.  Please  see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set  up the map.
    E/Google Maps Android API(5184): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
I/Google Maps Android API(5184): Failed to contact Google servers.  Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.

Comment: remove google play service lib , clean your pro and build it again. import google play service app lib to emulator , add it your project run and build broject now sign it again and run apk